# How to check elements type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need help )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Om2t.png)

```
return (
        <ButtonWrapperStyled>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <Button {...getRootProps()}>Загрузить</Button>

            {files.map((file) => {//file maybe FileProps or File type
                if (file) {// How can I check file type here?
                    return <div>{file.fileId}</div>
                } else {
                    return <div>{file.fileId}</div>
                }
            })}
        </ButtonWrapperStyled>
)
```

I typed array, it may be FileProps or File type.
How can I check it correctly in files.map?

I can't resolve this issue

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Give a [mre], not a screenshot.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with if else statement and same return values? Please provide your defined File and Fileprop types as well. You need to use type guards. There is no way to determine typescript type on runtime.
Read more about typeguards: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use type guards [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
type File = {
  fileId: number;
};

type FileProps = {
  name: string;
  size: number;
};

const files: (FileProps | File)[] = [];

files.map((file) => {
  if ('fileId' in file) {
    return <div>{file.fileId}</div>;
  } else {
    return <div>{file.name}</div>;
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the first option doesn't work?

```
// This option doesn't work, why?
{files.map((file) => {
    if (file?.fileId) {
        return <div>{file.fileName}</div>
    } else {
        return <div>{file.name}</div>
    }
})}
//This option works
{files.map((file) => {
    if ('fileId' in file) {
        return <div>{file.fileName}</div>
    } else {
        return <div>{file.name}</div>
    }
})}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).